# How to show that $ \int_0^1\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}dx$ diverges?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that the following integral diverges:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x^2}dx
$$
I tried to use Dirichlet theorm but without any success. How can I show it without using taylor?

Comment: Have you tried substituting $y=1/x$?

Answer (score 8):

**HINT**

Substitute $\frac1x\rightarrow t$ to get $\int_1^{\infty}\sin(t)dt$